# Resampling a dataframe based on depth column

Tags: pandas, resampling

I have two dataframe which the `key` is depth. One has > 2k values the other only 100, but the min and the max depth are the same. I would like to upsample the small dataframe (which has only one column) at the same size of the bigger one and repeat the same value of a column between two depths.

I've tried using concatenate and resampling but I'm stuck when I want to find the same depth since the two dataframes depths do not have exactly the same values

I have this:

```
df_small:
    depth  Litholog
0  38.076       2.0
1  39.546       2.0
2  41.034       4.0
3  55.133       3.0
4  69.928       2.0
```

and this:

```
df_big:
     depth  
0  21.3360         
1  35.2044         
2  37.6428        
3  41.7576         
4  41.9100         
5  48.7680         
6  53.1876         
7  56.0832         
8  58.3692         
9  62.1792
```

I would like this:

```
df_result:
     depth  Litholog
0  21.3360         2
1  35.2044         2
2  37.6428         2
3  41.7576         4
4  41.9100         4
5  48.7680         4
6  53.1876         4
7  56.0832         3
8  58.3692         3
9  62.1792         2
```

I tried several approach but without success. Many thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If change sample data for same max and min value in both is possible use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
#change sample data for same min,max by df_big
print (df_small)
     depth  Litholog
0  21.3360       2.0
1  39.5460       2.0
2  41.0340       4.0
3  55.1330       3.0
4  62.1792       2.0

df = pd.merge_asof(df_big, df_small, on='depth')
print (df)
     depth  Litholog
0  21.3360       2.0
1  35.2044       2.0
2  37.6428       2.0
3  41.7576       4.0
4  41.9100       4.0
5  48.7680       4.0
6  53.1876       4.0
7  56.0832       3.0
8  58.3692       3.0
9  62.1792       2.0
```